# root finding for scalar multivariable function

Tags: numpy, scipy

Edit: More specifically, I'm looking for an practical way to plot the shape of the zeros of a scalar function with 2 variables. So the values only need to precise up to the resolution of the 2D mesh grid I choose. e.g. f(x,y) = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) - 4 should give me a circle.

The problem is that fsolve requires a vector function, so

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def a(x): return sin(x[0]) + cos(x[1])
nodes = fsolve(a,(.1,.2))
```

won't work. Is there any workaround? e.g.
    def a(x): return [sin(x[0]) + cos(x[1]),0]

but it only outputs 1 solution (array([-1.37079633,0.2]) instead of all the possible zeros).

Comment: How would you expect it to return an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: sorry, I agree that it is a bad example

Comment: @pcr: could you make a more reasonable example showing what you want?

Comment: @talonmies `def b(x): return [x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 - 2,2]` is not much better than my previous example. For any smooth fn, the zeros will form lines/loop (infinite), and my intention is to numerically find and sample what the lines/loops are.

Comment: There's no choice but to vary your initial guesses. You have to make some sort of mesh of the space you're interested in, try lots of initial guesses in that mesh and save the coordinates of the zeros. Then doing a scatter plot should reveal some of its shape. But in general, nothing can find multiple zeros for you. I'm guessing that under the hood `fsolve` uses non-linear methods like semi-Newton methods, and to get multiple zeros you literally have to use multiple guesses. And even then, there's never a guarantee it can converge to all the relevant ones for your purposes.

Comment: @EMS Thanks. Alternatively, I also saw a description of how people might have done this: do several initial random walk (like your guesses) until you encounter a sign change, and then find the next closest sign change and so on (repeated bisection method) -> too expensive to be implemented in python?

Comment: If you use NumPy that won't be too expense, probably on the order of Matlab slowness. But if you have access to a cluster, this would be embarrassingly parallel, so you could dedicate the head processor to moving along and finding the root brackets (sign changes), then shipping off the bracket boundary to the next available processor to actually compute the root. There's no need to necessarily do bisection. You can also do golden section line search, or Newton's method in the bracket if you have an easy derivative calculation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to diagnose the behaviour of your 2D function and its zeros, you are much better of generating a 2D grid of values, and plotting with something like matplotlib's `pcolor`. Then if you really need to precisely find where the zeros are, you know where to start `fsolve` looking.

In principal it might be possible to automate this procedure, if you know something about your function, e.g. how many zeros there are for each value of y, then you will know how many times you need to apply fsolve around each minimum. This may or may not prove to be sufficiently robust. But there is no general solution to finding all the zeros of an arbitrary nonlinear function, particularly not for multiple dimensions.